# Best way to sort two results from string

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I've got the results back from a function stored as a string:

```
TF00, 24 percent complete
TF01, 100 percent complete
TF02, 0 percent complete
TF03, 5 percent complete
```

but I need to sort it (reverse numerically) by the second item, so it looks like this:

```
TF01, 100 percent complete
TF00,  24 percent complete
TF03,  5 percent complete
TF02,  0 percent complete
```

What's the most Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Each string is one line? Or it's a single string with all the lines?

Comment: One long string: fileName + ", " + percentValue + " percent complete\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume s is the str, then:

```
print '\n'.join(sorted(s.split('\n'), key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1])))
```

Comment: And to sort it - reverse numerically: r = '\n'.join(sorted(s.split('\n'), key =lambda x: int(x.split()[1])))
r = r.split("\n")
r.reverse()
r = "\n".join(r)

Comment: If sort is reverse numerically, just do that in sorted function, like:    `print '\n'.join(sorted(s.split('\n'), key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]), reverse=True))`